# parsing line with quotes in CMD

Tags: parsing, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

How to fix this error?

```
@echo off 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM LINES FOR TEST:
REM         <td><span><span>41</span><span style="display: none;">111</span><div
REM style="display: none;">190</div><span class="" style="">.</span><span>197</span><span
REM style="display: none;">24</span><span></span>.<span style="display: 
REM inline;">132</span><span style="display: none;">39</span>.<span 
REM style="display: inline;">186</span></span></td> 

SET line=inline;">132</span><span style="display: none;">39</span>.<span 

FOR /F "tokens=1-20 delims=<>" %%A IN (%line%) DO (
echo A:%%A + B:%%B + C:%%C + D:%%D + E:%%E + F:%%F + G:%%G + H:%%H + I:%%I + J:%%J + K:%%K + L:%%L
FOR %%? in ( "%%A", "%%B", "%%C", "%%D", "%%E", "%%F", "%%G", "%%H", "%%I", "%%J") DO (
SET $=%%?
echo $:!$!
)
pause
)
```

I want to separate the line by tags. But I got error: > not expected

**Edit:**

```
I tried this:
SET line=inline;">132</span><span style="display: none;">39</span>.<span 
FOR /F usebackq^ tokens^=1-20^ delims^=^>^< %%A IN (^"%line%^") DO (
echo A:%%A + B:%%B + C:%%C + D:%%D + E:%%E + F:%%F + G:%%G + H:%%H + I:%%I + J:%%J + K:%%K + L:%%L
FOR %%? in ( "%%A", "%%B", "%%C", "%%D", "%%E", "%%F", "%%G", "%%H", "%%I", "%%J") DO (
SET $=%%?
echo $:!$!
)
pause
)
```

Error:
System cannot find file inline ">132

**Another test** - I moved the lines to file and no error

`FOR /F "delims= " %%? IN (html_2.txt) DO (
echo %%? 
FOR /F "tokens=1-20 delims=><" %%A IN ("%%?") DO (
echo A:%%A + B:%%B + C:%%C + D:%%D + E:%%E + F:%%F + G:%%G + H:%%H + I:%%I + J:%%J + K:%%K + L:%%L
FOR %%? in ( "%%A", "%%B", "%%C", "%%D", "%%E", "%%F", "%%G", "%%H", "%%I", "%%J") DO (
SET $=%%~?
echo $:!$!
)
pause
)
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%A IN (html_2.txt) DO (
    set a=%%A 
    set a=!a:"=\q!
    echo a=!a!
    FOR /F "tokens=1-26 delims=<>" %%a in ( "!a!" ) DO ( 
        set a=%%a& echo $:!a:\q="!
        set b=%%b& echo $:!b:\q="!
        set c=%%c& echo $:!c:\q="!
        set d=%%d& echo $:!d:\q="!
        set e=%%e& echo $:!e:\q="!
        set f=%%f& echo $:!f:\q="!
        set g=%%g& echo $:!g:\q="!
        set h=%%h& echo $:!h:\q="!
        rem repeat thru to z
        )
    pause
    )
```

Comment: Hey, it works! Does the \q= removes the qoutes? Thank, you. I thought Nobody would help me to solve it. But you did.

Comment: initially `set a=!a:"=\q!` takes out all the doublequotes that are on the input line. `!a:\q="!` converts back just before output. It is limited to 13 html tags per line.

Comment: @John **exclamation mark in input**: I think you would you need a read thru (pass 1) with `DELIMS=!` to rewrite file then process that file wtih above code (pass 2).

Comment: @Skip R - Sorry, but your code is nonsense! You could remove the `set a=!a:"=\q!` and will work also (and better!). Also the exclamation mark handling isn't correct.

Comment: @jeb "nonsense" is not constructive. Which bit - all of it?  `set a=!a:"=\q!` is required to remove double quotes (dquotes) from the input file data. If you do not do this `FOR /F` will parse the data incorrectly. Consider the 5th `REM` line in OP code. That data in a file will not parse and split `">132</span><span style="display: none;"`. The syntax of `for /f` needs outer dquotes but reads the substituted var data dquotes as marker for end of the first argument `for` will process. This was the cleanest solution after a few hours testing - perhaps you should test code before dismissing it.

Comment: Sorry if you feel dismissed, that wasn't my intention, but your interpretation of the `FOR/F` command is wrong. It hasn't any problems with quotes, if you read from a file nor when you use delayed expansion like `FOR/F ...in ("!a!")`. I added an answer to clarify

Answer (score 1):

`<` and `>` are redirection operators, you need to escape them: `^>`

Comment: Is it not possible to change behavior of the for command to take the string not as a command but as a string? I have escaped but error is still there: `SET line=inline;"^>132^</span^>^<span style="display: none;"^>39^</span^>.^<span` Error: Cannot find file inline

Comment: `SET line=inline;"^>132^</span^>^<span style="display: none;"^>39^</span^>.^<span 

FOR /F "tokens=1-20 delims=<>" %%A IN ("%line%") DO (
echo A:%%A + B:%%B + C:%%C + D:%%D + E:%%E + F:%%F + G:%%G + H:%%H + I:%%I + J:%%J + K:%%K + L:%%L
FOR %%? in ( "%%A", "%%B", "%%C", "%%D", "%%E", "%%F", "%%G", "%%H", "%%I", "%%J") DO (
SET $=%%?
echo $:!$!
)
pause
)
`

Comment: Error: 
$:%?
System cannot find file §:?§u§?§YSTEM\GnuWin\bin.
Press any key to continue

Comment: delims=<> is not escaped and for %line% you might even have to double escape (^^^>) for FOR. As you can see, batchfiles are not optimal for dealing with HTML...

Comment: I'm not sure if %%? is legal either

Comment: Do you say, I should do some kind of escape in the delims definition? ... like delims=^>^<  ??? I use %% normally. **Do you also say, that when the CMD parses html code, the <> can result in unexpected results?**

Comment: I really don't understand what kind of escape do you mean. Can you show some code? My try: `SET line=inline;">132</span><span style="display: none;">39</span>.<span 
FOR /F usebackq^ tokens^=1-2^ delims^=^>^< %%A IN (^"%line%^") DO (
echo A:%%A + B:%%B + C:%%C + D:%%D + E:%%E + F:%%F + G:%%G + H:%%H + I:%%I + J:%%J + K:%%K + L:%%L
FOR %%? in ( "%%A", "%%B", "%%C", "%%D", "%%E", "%%F", "%%G", "%%H", "%%I", "%%J") DO (
SET $=%%?
echo $:!$!
)
pause
)
`

Comment: Then, if you say, that it is hard to parse html code, and that the problem is in escaping of <> ... why there is no error if I move the lines into file? `FOR /F "delims= " %%? IN (html_2.txt) DO (
echo %%? 
FOR /F "tokens=1-20 delims=><" %%A IN ("%%?") DO (
echo A:%%A + B:%%B + C:%%C + D:%%D + E:%%E + F:%%F + G:%%G + H:%%H + I:%%I + J:%%J + K:%%K + L:%%L
FOR %%? in ( "%%A", "%%B", "%%C", "%%D", "%%E", "%%F", "%%G", "%%H", "%%I", "%%J") DO (
SET $=%%~?
echo $:!$!
)
pause
)
)
`

Answer (score 0):

Here is shortened version of Skip R's code:

```
@echo off 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%A IN (html_2.txt) DO (
    set a=%%A 
    set a=!a:"=\q!
    echo a=!a!
    FOR /F "tokens=1-26 delims=<>" %%A in ( "!a!" ) DO ( 
        FOR %%Z in ( %%A, %%B, %%C, %%D, %%E, %%F, %%G, %%H, %%I, %%J) DO (
        set z=%%Z
        echo !z:\q="!
        )
    )
    pause
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your `FOR/F` loops.  It's the expansion of your variable `line` in `FOR/F ... in (^"%line%^")`.
Use delayed expansion here or better read the content from a file.

This handle your problem without respecting exclamation marks nor carets.

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1-26 delims=<>" %%A IN (html_2.txt) DO (
   echo a=%%A
   echo b=%%B
   echo c=%%C
   echo d=%%D
   echo e=%%E
   rem ...
   echo z=%%Z
)
```

With preservation of exclamation marks and carets you need to toggle the delayed expansion mode and save the values in temporary variables.
To disable the EOL-character, I set it to a character out of the delims.

```
@echo off 
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1-26 EOL=< delims=<>" %%A IN (html_2.txt) DO (
    set "paramA=%%A"
    set "paramB=%%B"
    set "paramC=%%C"
    rem ...
    set "paramZ=%%Z"

   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   echo a=!paramA!
   echo b=!paramB!
   echo c=!paramC!
   rem ...
   echo z=!paramZ!
   endlocal
)
```

Tested with html_2.txt:

```
<td><span><span>41</span><span style="display: none;">111</span><div
style="display: none;">190</div><span class="" style="">.</span><span>197</span><span
style="display: none;">24</span><span></span>.<span style="display: 
inline;">132</span><span style="display: none;">39</span>.<span 
style="display: inline;">186</span></span></td>
```